# Validate URL in Redux Form

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am using [redux-form](https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/) package for my React Redux form. I know how to do validation for other fields e.g email, name.

However, I do not know how to validate a URL in redux-form. What is the format that I should check for in my URL field?

```
const renderField = ({ input, label, type, placeholder, message , meta: { touched, error, warning } }) => (
    <Form.Field >
      <label className="new-font">{label}</label>
      <Input {...input} type={type} className="new-font" placeholder={placeholder} />
      {touched && error &&
        <div>
          <Label
            basic
            color='red'
            pointing
            className="new-font"
          >
          {error}
          </Label>
        </div>
      }

      {(input.name === ('desc') || input.name === ('hyperlink')) ?
       <Message compact>
         {message}
       </Message> : <span></span>
      }
    </Form.Field>
  )

function validate(values){
  const errors ={};
  if(!values.name){
    errors.name='Please let me know who I should thank!';
  }
  if(!values.email){
    errors.email='Please enter an email address';
  }
  if (values.email && !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values.email)
  ) {
    errors.email = 'Please enter a valid email address e.g test@gmail.com'
  }
  if(values.desc && values.desc.length > 50 ){
    errors.desc="Key in 50 characters or less";
  }
  if(!values.hyperlink){
    errors.hyperlink="Insert a URL address here to your favourite website!";
  }
  return errors;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since redux form allows you to [customize](https://redux-form.com/7.2.0/docs/api/field.md/#2-a-stateless-function) its `Field` components, you can use plain HTML to create an input field that validates urls like this:

```
<input id="my_url" name="my_url" value type="url" placeholder="your website goes here" pattern="https?://.+" required >
```

Comment: would be better if I know the format of the URL validation. This way I can show the error message when user input invalid URL. But thanks. It's a neat workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can use validator package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) that has many validations for email, url, ascii .... so you can import package and use it in form :

```
import validator from 'validator'

function validate(values){
  const errors ={};

  if (!validator.isURL(values.hyperlink)) {
    errors.hyperlink = 'This field can not be link'
  } 

  return errors
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can alter your validate function with this :

```
  function validate(values){
      const errors ={};
      if(!values.name){
        errors.name='Please let me know who I should thank!';
      }
      if(!values.email){
        errors.email='Please enter an email address';
      }
      if (values.email && !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values.email)
      ) {
        errors.email = 'Please enter a valid email address e.g test@gmail.com'
      }
      if(values.desc && values.desc.length > 50 ){
        errors.desc="Key in 50 characters or less";
      }
      if(!values.hyperlink){
        errors.hyperlink="Insert a URL address here to your favourite website!";
      }
      else if(!isUrlValid(values.hyperlink) ) {
             errors.hyperlink="Insert a valid URL";
      }
      return errors;
    }
    const isUrlValid = (userInput) => {
        var res = userInput.match(/(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g);
        if(res == null)
            return (false );
        else
            return (true);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I just released a new version of my package [redux-form-validators](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-form-validators).
It allows you to write simpler code, like this:

```
let validations = {
  name: required({ msg: 'Please let me know who I should thank!' }),
  email: [required(), email()],
  desc: length({ max: 50 }),
  hyperlink: url(),
}
```